# How to disable accessor return type warnings?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, warnings, getter-setter, accessor

I have an object that has to be of different types internally, but that I always want to return as a string. So I declared the object as 'id' and wrote a getter method that always returns NSString*. Everything is working as it should, and XCode is complaining "Type of property 'X' does not match type of accessor 'setX:'" as expected. Since I do want this behaviour though, does anybody know how to tell XCode that I do, in fact, want this, and would rather not see this warning all the time? Kind of like the "__unused" directive for unused variables?

Thank you!
Max

Edit: Here's the code

**.h**

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) id wert;
- (void) setWert:(NSString *)value;
- (NSString *) wert;
```

**.m**

```
 @synthesize wert;

- (void) setWert:(NSString *)value
{
        wert = value;
}

- (NSString *) wert
{
        return wert;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are having problems with?

Comment: I can't seem to recreate this error. Can you post code and the exact error message?

Comment: added code sample in the original post. The error message is "Type of property 'wert' does not match type of accessor 'setWert:'"

Comment: @Max I still can't recreate this. You might have to create a sample project and isolate the issue. Are you on the latest version of Xcode?

Comment: @joerick thank you so much for your help! I've uploaded a sample project here: http://www.filedropper.com/test_22

Comment: I have also edited the code sample. I forgot the method declarations and the @synthesize. This definitely gives the warning

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in these lines:

```
@interface TestClass : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) id wert;

- (void) setWert:(NSString *)value;
- (NSString *) wert;

@end
```

Essentially, the `@property` notation is shorthand for declaring the accessor methods (with some attributes, admittedly). So it makes no sense here to declare it first as an `id`, and then as an NSString. Decide on the type that you want to expose for wert, and use that for the property declaration. I'd suggest:

```
@interface TestClass : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) id wert;

@end
```

Additionally, in the `.m`, you first @synthesize the property, then override the getter and setter. This means the only thing you're getting from the @synthesize is the instance variable.

You can declare instance variables in the @implementation block too. This would be a good place for you to declare the internal type:

```
@implementation TestClass
{
    NSString *wert;
}
```

But then if you're happy for other classes to call setWert: with anything other than NSString, you shouldn't change the type declaration for the setter. To do so would be assuming that `value` is an NSString. So your accessors should look like this:

```
- (void) setWert:(id)value
{
    // store wert as an NSString
}

- (id) wert
{
    // return wert as the original type
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did misunderstand what @property did. Even so, declaring the instance variable as `id wert` in `@implementation` leads to a crash with `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance...'`. I don't know why this doesn't work, but the way before did.

As for the accessor methods, `value` is always string, and to the outside world, `wert` is supposed to look like a NSString, but inside, it is and should be a bunch of different objects - from NSInteger to NSDate. Maybe that is not ideal but why did it work before then?

Comment: Okay, looks like I had it the wrong way around then. Declare the property as NSString (including the setters and getters) and then the instance variable as `id`. As for your crash, this is a different issue, you must have changed your logic somewhere.

Comment: That doesn't work either, then I'm getting errors elsewhere in the getter method: "No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'decimalValue'". It's a bit weird. Maybe I should just live with the warnings, but I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Probably, but where? I think I'll just leave it, after all, it's working. Thanks for your help, joerick!

Answer (score -1):

setting an `NSString *` to and `id` typed property wont cause an warning, but setting an `id` typed var to a `NSString *` property will... you can resolve with a typecast...

```
id someVar = @"string";
someObject.setStringProperty = (NSString *)someVar;
```